# SELECT FOR UPDATE holding entire table in MySQL rather than row by row

Tags: mysql, select, transactions, sql-update

I will have multiple clients entering data into a database and I must ensure that the transactions do not get intermingled.

I read in the documentation that `START TRANSACTION` and `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` locks each row that it reads:

> A SELECT ... FOR UPDATE reads the latest available data, setting exclusive locks on each row it reads. Thus, it sets the same locks a searched SQL UPDATE would set on the rows.
>
> See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

So I logged in one client and typed these statements:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM productMacAddress WHERE status='free' limit 8 FOR UPDATE;
```

> Pause here for second client entry....

```
UPDATE productMacAddress SET status='testing1' WHERE status='free' LIMIT 8;
COMMIT;
```

And in another client, I type:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM productMacAddress WHERE status='free' limit 4 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE productMacAddress SET status='testing2' WHERE status='free' LIMIT 4;
COMMIT;
```

But I am not able to `SELECT` anything from the table until the first client is completely done.  Why is this happening?  The documentation states it should lock row by row, especially since I `LIMIT 8`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default isolation level for InnoDB tables is repeatable read. When this isolation level is active we get the following behavior (quote from: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html):

> For locking reads (SELECT with FOR UPDATE or LOCK IN SHARE MODE),
>   UPDATE, and DELETE statements, locking depends on whether the
>   statement uses a unique index with a unique search condition, or a
>   range-type search condition. For a unique index with a unique search
>   condition, InnoDB locks only the index record found, not the gap
>   before it. For other search conditions, InnoDB locks the index range
>   scanned, using gap locks or next-key (gap plus index-record) locks to
>   block insertions by other sessions into the gaps covered by the range.

In other words: could you try using the primary key in the WHERE condition of the SELECT? So for instance instead of:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM productMacAddress WHERE status='free' limit 8 FOR UPDATE;
```

Try:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM productMacAddress WHERE id=10 FOR UPDATE;
```

in case id is the primary key. Any other column with a unique index on it would work too. When using non-unique columns in your WHERE clause InnoDB will lock a range of rows.

Comment: There is a little complicated cases that: when "SELECT FOR UPDATE" is followed with a WHERE statement such as:"WHERE (indexed_key= value1 or indexed_key=value2)", InnoDB will lock the whole table again instead of this two rows. Why is that?

Comment: `FOR UPDATE` should be before `WHERE` but for `WHERE (indexed_key= value1 or indexed_key=value2)` you should use `EXPLAIN` to see if `indexed_key` is used otherwise it will lock entire table. This might be helpful https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/271229/220814

Comment: @Ruben Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this. I have been struggling with this for a few hours now, and just couldn't understand the behaviour - but now it makes perfect sense. Thank you :-)