# Lock several rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242081/select-for-update-holding-entire-table-in-mysql-rather-than-row-by-row) it is not possible to hold several rows on a non indexed column. So I'm trying to lock several rows using the index column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a
(
    a int PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO a
VALUES (0),
       (1),
       (2),
       (3),
       (4),
       (5),
       (6),
       (7),
       (8),
       (9),
       (10),
       (11),
       (12),
       (13),
       (14);
```

Then in one connection:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE a IN (1, 2, 3) FOR
UPDATE;
```

In a second connection:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE a IN (7, 8, 9) FOR
UPDATE;
```

It works as expected.

However, if I increase the number of rows by one in the first connection:

```
BEGIN;

SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE a IN (1, 2, 3, 4) FOR
UPDATE;
```

Then the second connection times out.

For bigger tables I've seen a difference using:

```
FORCE INDEX (`PRIMARY`)
```

But not for this small table, so I suppose it is just a tip on using the index, but the planner will override it.

Is there a way to always only lock the rows in the query, probably by only allowing the index scan on that query?

Comment: Interesting. Can you include a `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` from a third connection with the associated stats for these two connections.

Comment: @danblack I cannot share the whole status, but the blocked transaction looks like:
```
 ------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 5 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
                                                                  RECORD LOCKS space id 252 page no 3 n bits 88 index `PRIMARY` of table `my_schema`.`a` trx id 109739 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
                                                                  Record lock, heap no 9 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format;
```